# SSH server that only serves one application

Tags: ssh, openssh

I want to set up a Linux box so that when you ssh into it you're talking to a specific application, and not ever to a shell.

I.e., I want to tell a user to log into `user_level_stuff@mybox`, and they get some nice super-safe (for them and for my box) application.  By preference, I'd like to have this on a non-traditional port (i.e., not port 22), but I can live without that.  Having my application be an ssh server is fine, as long as it can coexist on my box with a generic ssh server.  Having a route, either through error or malice, to a shell would be a *bad thing*.

How do I do this?

Comment: You could setup the users' shell to your application; so, on login, instead of launching `/bin/bash` you launch your own application. `sudo usermod --shell /path/to/your/app name_of_user`

Comment: Problem is the "SH" in "SSH" stands for "Shell". Perhaps instead you could run a standalone daemon that listens to a port and when a connection is received it starts the target process and pipes the TCP stream to the process's stdio? You would lose SSH's authentication and encryption, however.

Comment: It is precisely the authentication and encryption that I want to keep.